# J-unit with java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to create j-unit tests for each function below, but I don't know how to get started. In my case, it's really hard to use the function itself and test it within the unit case. I only know how to test specific values/lists. I need help with understanding how to test the functions themselves.

```
public class FindValues {           
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int[] x = new int[] {2,5,6};
        int y = 2;
        findLast(x, y);
        int[] x1 = new int[] {1,2,0};
        lastZero(x1,y);
        int[] x2  = new int[] {-3, 3, 5, 0};
        countPositive(x2,y);
        int[] x3  = new int[] {-6, 2, -1, 1};
        oddOrPos(x3);
    }   

    // findlast(int [] x, int y) takes an array of integers and should return the index of
    // the last element in the array that is equal to y.
    public static int findLast(int [] x, int y) {
        x = new int[]{2,5,6};
        y = 2;
        for (int i=x.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
            if (x[i] == y) { 
                // System.out.println(i);
                return i;
            } 
        }
        return -1;          
    } //end FindLast

// lastZero(int [] x) takes an array of integers and should return the index of the last//0 in x.
    public static int lastZero (int[] x, int y) {
        x = new int[]{1,2,0};
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int countPositive (int[] x, int y) {
        //Returns the number of positive elements in Xint count = 0;
        x = new int[]{-3, 3, 5, 0};
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] > 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        return count;           
    }

    public static int oddOrPos(int[] x) {
        //Return numbers in x that are either odd or positive or both int count = 0;
        int count = 0;
        x = new int[]{-6, 2, -1, 1};
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i]% 2 == -1 || x[i]% 2 == 1 || x[i] > 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        return count;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start with reading the [JUnit User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/).

Basically what you want to do is create a JUnit class that will test your `FindValues` class. Typically you would name this class after the one that is being tested. For example, `FindValuesTest`.

I'll get you started with a very basic test containing a basic assertion:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class FindValuesTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        int actualResult = FindValues.findLast(new int[]{1,2,3,4,2,5,8,2,9}, 2);
        assertEquals(7, actualResult);
    }

}
```

Note that I removed your hard-coded parameter values within `findLast`:

```
public static int findLast(int[] x, int y) {
    for (int i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (x[i] == y) {
            // System.out.println(i);
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

See how the test is providing inputs to your method and asserting that the output matches the expectation - this is what JUnit is meant to do. You execute some code you want to test and you verify the behavior of that code based on the input your test provided.